# jQuery conditional not working when being out of the ".bind" function

Tags: jquery, html

I have a mobile device tester in jQuery, in order to load or discard contents that are invalid on those devices **before page loads**, by actions contained on a conditional (for example, if is not mobile, it appends a HTML5 video)

I want my jQuery to make these actions on the DOM to have this updated struture in mind for page loading, and load the elements generated by these actions before the `.bind` function executes, but it just does not do any of the actions included on the conditional:

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);    },
    BlackBerry: function() {        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);    },
    iOS: function() {        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);    },
    Opera: function() {       return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);    },
    Windows: function() {        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/WPDesktop/i);    },
    any: function() {        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());    }};

if( isMobile.any() ) {
   $('.noMobile').addClass('easeInS');} 
else{ 
   $('.backgroundVideoC').append("<video preload='auto' poster='img/davidpreload.jpg' autoplay muted id='indexVideo'><source src='media/presen.webm' type='video/webm'><source src='media/presen.mp4' type='video/mp4'></video>");
   $('body').find('.indexVideo').addClass('easeInS');   
   $('.noMobile').remove();     }



$(window).bind("load", function() {
      $('.initialLoader').addClass('easeOutS');
      $('.initialHi').addClass('runWeb');}
```

If I set the conditional INSIDE the .bind function, it does work, but I want my `.bind` function to have in mind the DOM generated by the previous actions, not to make those actions once the website is loaded. Is this possible?

Comment: The dom is not ready when you try to add class or append video.

Comment: Thank you. So, how could I add a video only when is a HTML5 video compatible browser, and have it in mind for .bind function? If it is not a compatible browser I wouldn't like it to be loaded...

Comment: Just wrap you function in a DOM ready handler : http://pastebin.com/TCMScrU2

Comment: very grateful. Did not know that ready and bind could be used at the same time.

Comment: Actually, bind is just an event handler (which is deprecated now and should be replaced by `.on`), you can use it an unlimited time.